# Unexpected error using create-react-native-app:

Tags: reactjs, react-native, yarnpkg

Attempting to use create-react-native-app and falling at the first hurdle here.

I think the problem is when Yarn attempts to install dependencies:

```
yarn install v0.27.5
[1/4] Resolving packages...
warning react-native > connect@2.30.2: connect 2.x series is deprecated
error An unexpected error occurred: "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/expo/node-websql/e364fa65146a9e2157a19e5c719e7702c2b6b87a/package.json: connect ETIMEDOUT 90.207.238.183:443".
info If you think this is a bug, please open a bug report with the information provided in "D:\\users\\jamie\\WebstormProjects\\hang\\hang-app\\yarn-error.log".
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/install for documentation about this command.
```

Failed to install

What's odd is that I ran create-react-native-app on this machine last week to test it out and everything was fine.

Does anyone have any idea about what might be going on here?

Answer (score 0):

The error message says towards the end of the 4th line: `connect ETIMEDOUT`, which I assume means that Yarn timed out while downloaded that `package.json` file.

I just tried pasting the URL in my browser and it loaded, so if you try again it might just work!

Comment: Ok, making progress! raw.githubusercontent.com was blocked by my ISP (Phising/malware, sigh...) so I've whitelisted it. Now I'm getting an error
`error Received malformed response from registry for undefined. The registry may be down.`

Comment: Hmm, that sounds like a similar problem with something being blocked. Not sure if it will help, but maybe try `yarn install --verbose` to get some more debug output?

Comment: Switched off the ISP Blocking system entirely and everything is working fine now! Thanks for your help. (And no thanks to Sky Internet).

Comment: Well if you're using Github you're *obviously* a hacker and should be blocked 